# Google Analytics not tracking the events correctly

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using google analytics (analytics.js) to track a couple of buttons and facebook and twitter for social part but the problem is since the last Saturday that I configured the analytics code, can't see my events registered in my dashboard and it's strange because If I open the developers console of Chrome or Firefox can see the request and is returning 200 OK so, I don't know what's the exactly error.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="my_button">My button</a>
<a href="#" id="my_facebook_button">My Facebook Button</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My tweet body!&url=http://mywebsite.com"></a>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXXXXXXX',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.2'
        });

        //Track FB Share function
        FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(targetUrl) {
            ga('send', {
                'hitType': 'social',
                'socialNetwork': 'Facebook',
                'socialAction': 'Share',
                'socialTarget': 'http://giftagiftcard.com'
            });
        });    

    };
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
    // Google analytics
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-58646812-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'hitCallback': function() {
            console.log('Analytics is sending data');
        }
    });

    //Twitter Web Intents
    window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
        var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
        js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

    //Track twitter tweets
    function trackTwitter(intent_event) {
        if (intent_event) {             
            ga('send', {
                'hitType': 'social',
                'socialNetwork': 'Twitter',
                'socialAction': 'Tweet',
                'socialTarget': 'http://mywebsite.com/'
            });
        }
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
$(function() {

$('#my_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ga('send', 'My button', 'button', 'click', 'My button!');

});

$('#my_facebook_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'The name',
        link: 'http://mywebsite.com',
        picture: 'http://thepicture.png',
        caption: 'The caption',
        description: 'The description'
    },
        function(response) {
        }
    );
});

});
```

Actually, Facebook and twitter open the popup to share or tweet but facebook is not detecting the FB.Event.subscribe.

So, my errors are:

- I don't know if my GA events are wrong but the request return 200 OK and I can't see the events in my dashboard.
- Facebook is not detecting the Event.subscribe to once the user share,    record the event

I hope someone knows what are the issues with my code.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line, in your main.js, looks off:

```
 ga('send', 'My button', 'button', 'click', 'My button!');
```

"My button" doesn't look like a GA method like 'event'.

Comment: That's true, should be: ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'My button!');, I just fix it and I run the click and it's returning 200 ok too but I can't see the event in my dashboard.

Comment: You can check in your real-time reports, as data doesn't get processed for up to 24 hours.

Comment: Yep, it's true.. the vents are tracked correctly but not the social events... it's normal that only in the Real-Time reports only can see the normal events but no the social?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) plugin - very useful